# My custom product type is not sorting properly when using the sort functionality in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I developed a plugin that adds a custom type "Metal" to the products. Everything works more than nice except the sorting on the front website. When I sort the products in the shop page from high to low I can clearly see that my products aren't sorted properly. They're sorted LAST. What might be the reason of this? That's what I'm updating when adding a new product with custom type of "Metal":

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', $price );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', $price );
delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price');
```

I read somewhere that the sorting functionality of wordpress uses the `_price` and `_regular_price` fields to sort the products. As we can see I'm clearly inserting proper values of these fields but the sorting is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are the products sorted correctly if you call the archive/overview Page wit this URL-Params?

- ?orderby=price-desc
- ?orderby=price

That should do the trick. Another reason could be a conflict with a caching plugin if you don't exclude pages with URL-Params.

Comment: `?orderby=price-desc` is the default parameter value when I click on the sort High to Low and when I change it to `?orderby=price` it becomes a total mess, no order at all. I have only WooCommerce and my plugin activated.

Comment: OK, that sounds strange. Actually it should work with the parameters by default. Do you have a URL to your project?

Comment: Im working locally. I noticed that I was storing the `_price` and `_regular_price` fields with wrong format. They were like `61,478.37` but that's not what WooCommerce expects. I changed the format to `61478.37` but it's still not working. https://i.imgur.com/XHWWUgy.png https://i.imgur.com/sJIar4N.png